# Voice Recognition (converting voice to text)

Tags: python, linux, voice-recognition

I have code to convert voice to written text, I want to save the written text after it's converted to files that can be accessed later, how do I do it in the following code?

```
import speech_recognition as sr


def main():

    r = sr.Recognizer()

    with sr.Microphone() as source:
        r.adjust_for_ambient_noise(source)

        print("Please say something to start recording the lecture ")

        audio = r.listen(source)

        print("Recognizing Now .... ")


        # recognize speech using google

        try:
            print("You have said \n" + r.recognize_google(audio))
            print("Audio Recorded Successfully \n ")


        except Exception as e:
            print("Error :  " + str(e))




        # write audio
        with open("recorded.wav", "wb") as f:
            f.write(audio.get_wav_data())


if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

I tried to create another python file and run it as .txt but it saves the code not recoreded one

Answer (score 1):

In your `def main():` function you need to open a text file using `open()`, something similar to as shown:

```
transcript = open('transcript.txt', 'w')
```

after that where you are using `print("You have said \n" + r.recognize_google(audio))`
You have to write the data coming from `r.recognize_google(audio)` to the above `transcript.txt` text file using `transcript` file descriptor

```
transcript.write(r.recognize_google(audio))
```

Also you need to make sure to close the open file descriptor using `transcript.close()`

Modified your code slightly to show how you can do it

```
import speech_recognition as sr


def main():

    transcript = open('transcript.txt', 'w')
    r = sr.Recognizer()

    with sr.Microphone() as source:
        r.adjust_for_ambient_noise(source)

        print("Please say something to start recording the lecture ")

        audio = r.listen(source)

        print("Recognizing Now .... ")


        # recognize speech using google

        try:
            print("You have said \n" + r.recognize_google(audio))
            transcript.write(r.recognize_google(audio))
            print("Audio Recorded Successfully \n ")
        except Exception as e:
            print("Error :  " + str(e))

        # write audio
        with open("recorded.wav", "wb") as f:
            f.write(audio.get_wav_data())
            f.close()
    
    transcript.close()


if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```